# Django REST framework JWT checks user from database with every request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm using Django REST framework JWT library for authentication in my django application. And I thought the whole idea of using JSON Web Token Authentication was NOT having a database trip in every request.
But it still retrieves user's data (which is stored in the token's PAYLOAD) from database per request.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The webtoken mechanism and the server authentication internals are rather orthogonal.

The web token just allows the holder to say who they are.  It is similar to holding a user's username and password, except the token can be revoked without the user having to learn a new password.  This authentication technique has nothing to do with whether the server will do a database access.

If you wish to eliminate a DB access during authentication on the server, you can use some sort of authentication caching mechanism like [django-cached_authentication_middleware](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cached_authentication_middleware).